# Which Magento 2 core function creates the url for the static folder files including css, js and images

Tags: magento2, cache, url, static-content-deploy, parameter

I want to add a parameter at the end of the static content urls, but i am unable to find a global method where i can make a change and it starts reflecting on the all static content urls.

My file and code where i tried making the changes:

File path: `vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Repository.php`

code that i tried to modify:

```
public function createAsset($fileId, array $params = [])
    {
        $this->updateDesignParams($params);
        list($module, $filePath) = self::extractModule($fileId);
        if (!$module && $params['module']) {
            $module = $params['module'];
        }

        if (!isset($params['publish'])) {
            $map = $this->getRepositoryFilesMap($fileId, $params);
            if ($map) {
                $params = array_replace($params, $map);
            }
        }

        $isSecure = isset($params['_secure']) ? (bool) $params['_secure'] : null;
        $themePath = isset($params['theme']) ? $params['theme'] : $this->design->getThemePath($params['themeModel']);
        $context = $this->getFallbackContext(
            UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_STATIC,
            $isSecure,
            $params['area'],
            $themePath,
            $params['locale']
        );
        return $this->fileFactory->create(
            [
                'source' => $this->assetSource,
                'context' => $context,
                'filePath' => $filePath."?mytest='value'",
                'module' => $module,
                'contentType' => $this->assetSource->getContentType($filePath)
            ]
        );
    }
```

Where `"?mytest='value'"`, is my custom parameter that i want to pass globally for all the static files that load from my **pub/static** folder through web url.

Example relative url that i want to load for all the static content urls: `en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bootstrap.js?mytest='value'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer for my above question.

URLs that are created during the page load time are create from the file:

```
Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File
```

In the method:

```
getUrl()
```

Requirejs dependency urls are loaded from the `requirejs-config.js` file.

I hope this answer helps others looking to modify functionality related to static urls.